# could to describe past ability

Tags: grammar

Someone was lost in desert for 3 days. When we found him, we said to him

> "How could you survive in desert those 3 days?"

Is the usage of "**could**" correct in this sentence?

Comment: Depends on the context in what you want the sentence to be delivered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Could' is not correct in this context because it is a modal auxiliary verb, which implies capability. For example, "He could have reached the airport earlier had there not been any traffic". However, since the person has already been found (which is past tense) the correct verb to use is 'did'. Also, the word 'those' is superfluous in your case. Hence the sentence should read as follows.

> "How did you survive in the desert for 3 days?"

For your reference, have a look at these lists of verbs. You can also try to form sentences of your own with them.

> [Irregular verbs](https://languageonschools.com/blog/english-irregular-verbs-list/)
>
> [Regular verbs](https://cla.univr.it/webclass/castelli/b1/verbs/regular%20verbs%20list.pdf)

Comment: Can we say to him "how could you have survived in desert for 3 days?"

Comment: You can say "How did he survive in the desert for 3 days?"